# decorator function syntax python

Tags: python, decorator

I am learning decorator functions in python and I am wrapping my head around the @ syntax.

Here is a simple example of a decorator function which calls the relevant function twice.

```
def duplicator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If I understand correctly, it appears that:

```
@duplicator
def print_hi():
    print('We will do this twice')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
print_hi = duplicator(print_hi)
print_hi()
```

However, let's consider if I move to a more complex example. E.g. instead of calling the function twice, I want to call it a user-defined amount of times.

Using an example from here: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

```
def repeat(num_times):
    def decorator_repeat(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(num_times):
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        return wrapper_repeat
    return decorator_repeat
```

I can call this via:

```
@repeat(num_times=4)
def print_hi(num_times):
    print(f"We will do this {num_times} times")
```

However, this is most certainly not equivalent to:

```
print_hi = repeat(print_hi)
```

Because we have the extra argument of `num_times`.

What am I misunderstanding? 
Is it equivalent to:

```
print_hi = repeat(print_hi, num_times=4)
```

Comment: I believe you pretty much got it right.

Comment: `repeat(num_times)` returns a function and that function is used to decorate `print_hi`.

Comment: `@deco def foo` is equivalent to `foo = deco(foo)`, and `@deco(args) def foo` is equivalent to `foo = deco(args)(foo)`. Actually it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the case of the `repeat` decorator, the equivalent is:

```
print_hi = repeat(num_times=4)(print_hi)
```

Here, `repeat` takes a `num_times` argument and returns the `decorator_repeat` closure, which itself takes a `func` arguments and returns the `wrapper_repeat` closure.

Answer (score 4):

`repeat(num_times)` returns a function and that function is used to decorate `print_hi`.

```
@repeat(num_times=4)
def print_hi(num_times):
    ...
```

amounts to

```
f = repeat(num_times)
print_hi = f(print_hi)
```

The function that `repeat` returns is `decorator_repeat`, which decorates `print_hi`.