# Syntax of call of a decorator function in python

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

This is from a code snippet in Serious Python and I am having issues in understanding the call syntax.  The `check_user_is_not` is a decorator factory which returns a decorator. Rest of the syntax is also straight forward. The factory is defined as below.

```
def check_user_is_not(username):
    def user_check_decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.get('username') == username:
                raise Exception("This user is not allowed to get food")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return user_check_decorator
```

The issue is in the call.

```
class Store(object):
    def get_food(self, username, food):
        return self.storage.get(food)

Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")(Store.get_food)   # Statement 1
Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("admin")(Store.get_food)     # Statement 2
```

Statement 1 and statement 2 is causing a problem in my comprehension. What is `check_user_is_not("user123")`? If this is a function being returned and then we are calling that function with another function `Store.get_food`, then the syntax should be
`Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")( (Store.get_food) ) # not sure if valid`

I have put extra brackets to treat it as call. How should this statment be interpreted?

I have checked the other decorator questions, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606101/decorator-function-syntax-python) and did find similar code as  `print_hi = repeat(num_times=4)(print_hi)`.

Are these two statements valid and the same?

```
Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")( (Store.get_food) ) # not sure if valid`
#vs
Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")(Store.get_food)
```

Are there any specific names for this type of call?

Comment: I don't understand why you think extra brackets are required. `check_user_is_not(<whatever>)` returns a function, you call that function, `check_user_is_not(<whatever>)(<something else>)`... There is no name for this, this is just a regular function call, like any other

Comment: So, `check_user_is_not("user123")( (Store.get_food) )` is valid, but the grouping parentheses is not necessary, it can just be `check_user_is_not("user123")( Store.get_food )`

Comment: thanks, so this acts as a general function call. Actually the parenthesis is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Does it make more sense if we write it as:

```
decorate = check_user_is_not("user123")
Store.get_food = decorate(Store.get_food)
```

`decorate` is a function (in this case `user_check_decorator`), we then call it to get another function (in this case `wrapper`). `wrapper` decorates `Store.get_food`.

It is true that:

```
Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")( (Store.get_food) )
Store.get_food = check_user_is_not("user123")(Store.get_food)
```

are the same (and valid), but perhaps not for the reason you think. It is the same idea as the following:

```
a = (1)
b = 1
assert a == b # a and b both equal 1
```

Comment: thanks, the line `Store.get_food = decorate(Store.get_food)`  is more clear. Guess the author of the book (Julien) wanted more brevity.